# Expected value of process involving the square of the sum of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Suppose that you are given two uniform random variables in the interval [0,1], call them $X_1, Y_1$. If we have that $(X_1 + Y_1)^2 > 1$, then the process is over. Otherwise, continue until $\sum_{i = 1}(X_i + Y_i)^2 > 1$ for the first time. What is the expected number steps in this process?

I tried looking at the distribution of the sum of two uniform random variables but the pdf is piecewise and that doesn't seem like a good approach. I also considered finding the expected value as $\sum_{a \geq 0} \mathbb{P}(N > a)$ where $N$ is desired variable, but again I can't find an expression for this probability.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $X,Y \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, and since $X,Y > 0$ we have
$$
(X+Y)^2>1 \iff X+Y > 1
$$
Now we have
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[X+Y<1]
 &= \int_0^1\mathbb{P}[X+Y<1,Y=y] f_Y(y)dy \\
 &= \int_0^1\mathbb{P}[X<1-y] f_Y(y)dy \\
 &= \int_0^1 F_X(1-y) f_Y(y)dy \\
\end{split}
$$

Can you complete this?

**HINT 2**

If we can assume $X_i, Y_i$ are independent of $X_k,Y_k$ for $i \ne k$, define $(X_k+Y_k)^2 = N_k$ and you are asking if $n$ is the minimum such that $\sum_{i=1}^n N_i > 1$, then what is $\mathbb{E}[n]$.

By Wald's Theorem,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n N_i = \mathbb{E}[n] \mathbb{E}[N_i],
$$
so $\mathbb{E}[n] \ge \lceil 1/\mathbb{E}[N_i] \rceil$.

To find the distribution of $N_i$ you can use a trick like in the above first hint, i.e.
$$
F_N(x) = \mathbb{P}[N_i < x] = \mathbb{P}\left[X_i + Y_i < \sqrt{x}\right],
$$
which you can now condition on $Y_i$.

To find the expectation, you don't need the entire distribution:
$$
\mathbb{E}[N_k]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[(X_k+Y_k)^2\right]
 = \int_0^1 \int_0^1(x+y)^2dA = \frac76.
$$

Comment: I think this is useful for the case that the process stops in 1 step, however what I need the most guidance on is that I don't see how this can generalize for the process stopping in $k$ steps ie when the first $k-1$ pairs are such that $(X_1 + Y_1)^2 + \ldots + (X_{k-1} + Y_{k-1})^2 \leq 1$ and then $(X_1 + Y_1)^2 + \ldots + (X_k + Y_k)^2 > 1$

Comment: @user825920 same trick really, please see the update

Comment: Thank you for the expanded explanation, I have never seen Wald's theorem before, and so I was wondering if you could go into more detail how you get that $\mathbb{E}[n] = ⌈1 / \mathbb{E}[N_i]⌉$. From what I can read online about Wald's Thm, it seems like it should be $\mathbb{E}[n] = \mathbb{E}[ \sum N_i] / \mathbb{E}[N_i]$.

Comment: @user825920 you are right but you are operating under assumption that $\sum N_i = 1$...

Comment: In the problem you continue until we have the total sum greater than 1, so I dont see why are we assuming that

Comment: @user825920 you define $n$ to be like that

Comment: $n$ is defined as the first time the sum of the $N_i$ exceeds 1, so the sum $\sum N_i$ may be larger than 1 right? For example, if $\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} N_i  = 0.99$ and then $N_n = 1$

Comment: @user825920 that's the reason you need to round up after division...

Comment: And if  $\sum^{n-1}N_i = 0.99$ and then $N_n=1.5$, now we have that the sum is larger than 1... so rounding is not a good solution for that

Comment: @user825920 this I fail to see. If you define $n$ to be the minimum integer such that $\sum_i N_i > 1$, then $\mathbb{E}[n] = \mathbb{E}[\sum_i N_i]/\mathbb{E}[N_1] \ge 1/\mathbb{E}[N_1]$ and if there is a smaller $n$ than you get rounding this expression on the RHS, that contradicts the definition.  It makes no difference what $N_n$ is in any particular instance.

Comment: So by your statement above you have produced a lower bound for what the expected value of $n$ is and not the exact value, by simulation you can see your statement is not accurate: the expected value of $n$ seems to be around 1.65 while the expected value for $N_1$ seems to be around 1.16.

Comment: @user825920 i misread your question - when you asked what is the expected # of steps, i thought you mean an integer, as opposed to real expected value. Did change my answer to reflect the lower bound instead of equality.

Comment: @user825920 also $\mathbb{E}[N_k] = 7/6$...